# How to click on a certain page within a web using "pagination"?

Tags: excel, vba, web, web-scraping, pagination

I have a procedure that opens a web page and counts how many pages there are inside it. I would then need to click on a certain page, for example, number 3. Does anyone know how to do it? I detail below the code of the macro. Thank you very much!

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim element As IHTMLElement
    Dim elements As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim numberOfPages As Double
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.navigate "https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html"
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Set html = ie.document
    Set elements = html.getElementsByClassName("container")
    Set ElementCol = html.getElementsByTagName("a")
    numberOfPages = ie.document.querySelectorAll(".setPage").Length
    'Here I want to click on a certain page, for example, number 3
    For Each ele In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("li")
        For Each element In elements
            If element.className = "container" Then
                'Do something
            End If
        Next element
    Next
    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below code

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim ie As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument
    Dim element As IHTMLElement

    Set ie = New InternetExplorer
    ie.Visible = True
    ie.Navigate "https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html"
    WaitIE ie
    Set html = ie.Document
    Set element = html.querySelector("a.setPage")
    element.setAttribute "data-value", "3" ' set the page number you want open
    element.click
    WaitIE ie

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub

Sub WaitIE(ie As InternetExplorer)

    Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
    Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents
    Loop
    Application.StatusBar = "Ready"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you will want to loop all pages (but also showing how to select a given page) you need to check what is the currently active page then loop the other pages. Wait conditions are required along with error handling to avoid stale element exceptions bubbling up as permission denied as well as element not found.

---

**Explanation:**

This

```
currentPage = CLng(.querySelector(".active").innerText)
```

finds the currently active page. The currently active page has a class attribute with value `active`. The `.` is a css [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors).

This

```
If page <> currentPage Then
```

ignores the currently active page in the loop over all pages.

This

```
cssSelector = ".setPage[data-value='" & page & "']"
```

defines the selector to select any given page by concatenating the page number into the `data-value` attribute. It is combined with class selector, `.`, of `setPage` to limit to relevant elements for page selection:

The  `[data-value='pageNumber']`, `pageNumber` is example page e.g. 2, is a css [attribute = value selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

If you examine the html below:

[image]

You can see that if the currently active page is 1 then there is a class attribute value = `active` and no `data-value` attribute. To select page two you can see the class value is currently `setPage` and the `data-value` is `2`.

This

```
.querySelector(cssSelector).Click
```

selects the next page in the loop.

This

```
Do
    On Error Resume Next
    num = CLng(.querySelector(".active").innerText)
    On Error GoTo 0
Loop Until num = page
```

loops until the selected page number has class attribute value active and its innerText value is = to the desired page i.e. with page 2 selection when num = 2 such that html changes to:

[image]

You can re-write this loop in a number of ways with different conditions but this one works just fine.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

'VBE > Tools > References: Microsoft Internet Controls
Public Sub GetData()
    Dim ie As Object, numberOfPages As Long, currentPage As Long, page As Long
    Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://cebra.com.ar/category/73/Juego-de-Construccion.html"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            numberOfPages = .querySelectorAll(".setPage").Length
            currentPage = CLng(.querySelector(".active").innerText)
            Dim cssSelector As String, num As Long
            For page = 1 To numberOfPages
                If page <> currentPage Then
                    cssSelector = ".setPage[data-value='" & page & "']"
                    .querySelector(cssSelector).Click
                    Do
                        On Error Resume Next
                        num = CLng(.querySelector(".active").innerText)
                        On Error GoTo 0
                    Loop Until num = page
                    While ie.Busy Or ie.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
                End If
            Next
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try these answers?